# Wordpress php filter admin_body_class not working

Tags: php, plugin-development, filters, body-class

I have the following function in a plugin I have built:

```
static function filter_add_body_classes( $body_classes ) {

    $new_classes = array();

    // Only when logged in
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return $body_classes;
    }

    // If viewing the site
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        $new_classes[] = 'sat-site';
    }

    // If theming is enabled
    if ( Skizzar_Admin_Theme::is_themed() ) {
        $new_classes[] = 'sat-theme';
    }

    // If a custom logo image is provided and the menu logo hiding option is not enabled
    if ( Skizzar_Admin_Theme_Options::get_saved_network_option( 'logo-image' ) && ! Skizzar_Admin_Theme_Options::get_saved_network_option( 'hide-menu-logo' ) ) {
        $new_classes[] = 'sat-custom-logo';
    }

    // If hide-top-paging option is enabled
    if ( Skizzar_Admin_Theme_Options::get_saved_network_option( 'hide-top-paging' ) ) {
        $new_classes[] = 'sat-hide-top-paging';
    }

    // If hide-post-search option is enabled
    if ( Skizzar_Admin_Theme_Options::get_saved_network_option( 'hide-post-search' ) ) {
        $new_classes[] = 'sat-hide-post-search';
    }

    // If hide-top-bulk option is enabled
    if ( Skizzar_Admin_Theme_Options::get_saved_network_option( 'hide-top-bulk' ) ) {
        $new_classes[] = 'sat-hide-top-bulk';
    }

    // If hide-user-role-changer
    if ( Skizzar_Admin_Theme_Options::get_saved_network_option( 'hide-user-role-changer' ) ) {
        $new_classes[] = 'sat-hide-user-role-changer';
    }

    // If hide-view-switch option is enabled
    if ( Skizzar_Admin_Theme_Options::get_saved_network_option( 'hide-view-switch' ) ) {
        $new_classes[] = 'sat-hide-view-switch';
    }

    // If hide-media-bulk-select option is enabled
    if ( Skizzar_Admin_Theme_Options::get_saved_network_option( 'hide-media-bulk-select' ) ) {
        $new_classes[] = 'sat-hide-media-bulk-select';
    }

    // If hide-comment-type-filter option is enabled
    if ( Skizzar_Admin_Theme_Options::get_saved_network_option( 'hide-comment-type-filter' ) ) {
        $new_classes[] = 'sat-hide-comment-type-filter';
    }

    // If enable-notification-center option is enabled
    if ( Skizzar_Admin_Theme_Options::get_saved_network_option( 'enable-notification-center' ) ) {
        $new_classes[] = 'sat-notification-center';
    }

    // Merge & return
    if ( is_array( $body_classes ) ) {
        return array_merge( $body_classes, $new_classes );
    }
    return $body_classes . ' ' . implode( ' ', $new_classes ) . ' ';

}
```

In my main plugin file I call it in 3 places using the following filters:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', array( 'Skizzar_Admin_Theme_Setup', 'filter_add_body_classes' ) );
add_filter( 'admin_body_class', array( 'Skizzar_Admin_Theme_Setup', 'filter_add_body_classes' ));
add_filter( 'login_body_class', array( 'Skizzar_Admin_Theme_Setup', 'filter_add_body_classes' ) );
```

This should add classes to the body based on options users pick for their plugin. The classes should be added to the **admin body**, **site** and **login page**. However, currently, it just adds to the site - so essentially `admin_body_class` and `login_body_class` are doing nothing.

Can anyone help me trouble shoot this - not getting any errors, just it's not doing anything

Comment: Are you hooking the filter inside any function? Maybe it's being called too late on admin. Or can you try debug to see if in admin it's returning on the first `if` where it check the user?

Comment: Hi @BrunoCantuaria - my filters aren't wrapped in a function no - they are called on the main plugin file page. How would I go about debugging this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About your issue in **admin body class**, WP Codex documentation [`admin_body_class`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_body_class/), class as string ( not array ), there are some of your function like `get_saved_network_option` not returning true that cause `$new_classes` not setted in array.

This code correct, we need return in string, but `$new_classes` maybe in string empty or not array.

```
return $body_classes . ' ' . implode( ' ', $new_classes ) . ' ';
```

For **login page class**, you are correct to set [`login_body_class`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_body_class) in array, BUT you set condition too early as @Bruno Cantuaria comment, take a look your code:

```
// Only when logged in
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    return $body_classes;
}
```

So thats why you class settings not return, it only work if user not logged-in. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @jevuska. Thanks for your reply - I'm afraid I don't completely understand - what should I change in my code in order to fix my issue?

Comment: For on login page, I think you just need to remove the code that I mention 
`if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) { return $body_classes; }`, if not, you need to decide which class that used in login page and put inside that code.

Comment: I see, you are right - this does work for the login page - my main issue though is gettig these classes to add to the admin body, and this does not work for that

Comment: Sorry I update my statement for admin body class, you need to test all class and enable all option that mention on code, and see if one or more class added in body.